# “Inspiration” versus “muse”

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I am writing the dedication section of a dissertation and wanted to write:

> To Bob and Joe, my inspiration and my muse.

Is using *inspiration* and *muse* redundant in that sentence? In the sense that am I saying

> To Bob and Joe, my inspiration and my inspiration.

A quick google of *muse* told me that *inspiration* was a synonym and now I am concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small distinction between *muse* and *inspiration,* namely that a muse is only a **source** of inspiration or ideas[¹](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muse)[²](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/muse). Somebody receives inspiration from spending time and interacting with the muse but the muse itself is not the inspiration in the sense of directly motivating a piece of work. By means of a [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) (creatio pro creatore – product for creator), a muse in this sense can also be called *inspiration.*

However, there are persons you would call *inspiration* but not *muse.* For example, if Bob‘s life and success inspired you to take on the troubles of acquiring a degree, you might call him your inspiration, but you would not call him your muse, unless he also “actively” provided inspiration by interacting with you. In particular, somebody with whom you never interacted (say, Albert Einstein) can be your inspiration, but not your muse.

So, if you explicitly use both terms:

> To Bob, my inspiration and muse.

this can be understood to say that Bob was not only a source of inspiration (muse) but also a role model (inspiration) for you. Something similar applies, if you explicitly distinguish between the two terms:

> To Bob, my inspiration, and Joe, my muse.

In this case I would understand Bob to be your role model, and Joe to have provided inspiration for you by means of interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the construction sounds marked because the words are synonyms.  It would be better to have "To Bob and Joe, my muses" or "To Bob and Joe, my inspirations."